# intent detection and slot filling using tensorflow.js

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow

I'm still getting up to speed with machine learning, but I'm aware of the papers on joint intent detection and slot filling by [Bing Liu & Ian Lane](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.01454.pdf), and another by [Xiaodong Zhang and Houfeng Wang](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/16/Papers/425.pdf) - and I'm sure there would be others.

There are several implementations available on GitHub:

- [liu/lane by brightmart](https://github.com/brightmart/slot_filling_intent_joint_model)
- [liu/lane by HadoopIt](https://github.com/HadoopIt/rnn-nlu)
- [liu/lane by applenob](https://github.com/applenob/RNN-for-Joint-NLU)

I'm hoping to be able to train a model using python and TensorFlow on the back-end, and then use the model in Node and browsers using [TensforFlow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/)

If I feed the training process with a limited set of patterns of the form:

```
flights from @City:origin to @City:destination @Date:date
flights from @City:origin to @City:destination @DatePeriod:datePeriod
airfares from @City:origin to @City:destination
...
```

...then the vocabulary would be fairly limited:

- flights
- from
- to
- airfares

Plus known entity values:

- Boston, New York...
- tomorrow
- next week
- saturday...
- first...
- january...

I have a few noob questions:

- Is this strategy valid?
- If my vocabulary is, say, 100 words then how big is the model that would have to be downloaded by the web app?
- How difficult would it be to implement the `.predict()` side in TensorFlow.js?
- Would there be any noticeable performance difference between the TensorFlow.js `.predict()` implementation and iterating through a list of regular expressions?